# Random Insert occuring with MySQL Coalesce query?

Tags: php, mysql, coalesce

I have the following query and it occasionally creates a random notification entry for a recipient id that does not meet the `WHERE` conditions of the query. What is wrong with the `WHERE` portion of my query that would be causing random inserts?

```
INSERT INTO
    notification (text,
        type,
        target_id,
        sender_id,
        recipient_id,
        data,
        timestamp,
        is_unread)
    SELECT DISTINCT '$text', 
        'comment', 
        '$id',
        '$senderId',
        COALESCE(comment.author_id, stream.author_id), 
        '$dataArray',
        '$timestamp', 
        '1'
    FROM 
        stream,
        comment 
    WHERE 
         (comment.author_id != '$senderId' AND comment.target_id = '$id')
      OR (stream.author_id != '$senderId' AND stream.id = '$id')
```

Comment: What is wrong with the where portion of my query that would be causing random inserts?

Comment: @BraydonBatungbacal We would need to see examples of the PHP variables being interpolated in the `WHERE` clause to speculate. Likely, it isn't the query as you've designed it causing problems, but the values of `$senderId, $id` or other variables causing problems.

Comment: The sample may be vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html), which is a very serious [security risk](http://bobby-tables.com/). Instead of interpolating values directly into the query, you should use a prepared statement and parameterize the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no join condition between your `stream` and `comment` tables.  You're effectively generating a Cartesian product, so you may have rows from `stream` included that are unrelated to `comment`, or vice versa.

I suggest you use the `JOIN` syntax and declare a condition for correlating rows from the two tables.